# Plotting the same figure in real time

Tags: matlab, simulink

So, I'm new to Simulink and have basic Matlab skills. I'm trying to plot an obstacle on the floor with a projector (which is connected as a 2nd monitor).
Anyway, I'd like to plot on the same figure all the time but I'm having problems. Sometimes the figure opens when starting the simulation and sometimes it does not. I can not for the life of me, figure out why.

The basic idea of the plot is to plot and obstacle on the floor that moves towards the user at the same speed as a treadmill is moving so to make it feel like its actually on the floor. I've removed all the elements of the figure and only show a red bar as an obstacle and a black background.

```
function plot_fcn(x)

persistent f 

    projectionArea=3; %3m - arbitrary, will change later
    barLength=0.35; %0.35m - arbitrary, will change later
    no_contact=true; % contact indicator
    treadmillSpeed=10/9; %4km/h = 10/9 m/s
    refreshRate= 100; % 100Hz
    obstacleIncrement=treadmillSpeed/refreshRate; % eye noticeable increment


if isempty(f)
        target=1; 
        beforeBar=1;
        p=[10;901;1680;1027.5];
        f = figure;
        set(f, 'MenuBar', 'none', 'ToolBar', 'none', 'Color','black');
        set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', p);
        % target=x;
        while (no_contact) 

            afterBar=projectionArea-barLength-beforeBar;

            Y = [beforeBar, barLength, afterBar;
                 beforeBar, barLength, afterBar;
                 beforeBar, barLength, afterBar];

            f=area(Y);

            set(f,'EdgeColor','red');
            f(1).FaceColor = [0 0 0];
            f(2).FaceColor = [1 0 0];
            f(3).FaceColor = [0 0 0];

            if beforeBar>=projectionArea-(target+barLength/2)
                no_contact=false
            else 
                beforeBar=beforeBar+treadmillSpeed*obstacleIncrement;
                pause(obstacleIncrement)
            end
        end

        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The simulation was not executed the second time you called the function and the persistent figure opened in the previous call was left open. In short, `if isempty(f)` contained too much code. And `drawnow` helps with iterative updates of the plot in the window.

```
function plot_fcn()

persistent f

projectionArea=3; %3m - arbitrary, will change later
barLength=0.35; %0.35m - arbitrary, will change later
no_contact=true; % contact indicator
treadmillSpeed=10/9; %4km/h = 10/9 m/s
refreshRate= 100; % 100Hz
obstacleIncrement=treadmillSpeed/refreshRate; % eye noticeable increment

target=1;
beforeBar=1;
if isempty(f) || ~ishandle(f) || ~isa(f,'matlab.ui.Figure')
    f = figure;
    set(f, 'MenuBar', 'none', 'ToolBar', 'none', 'Color','black');
else
    delete(findobj(f,'type','Area'))
end
figure(f); %focus window
while (no_contact)
    afterBar=projectionArea-barLength-beforeBar;

    Y = [beforeBar, barLength, afterBar;
        beforeBar, barLength, afterBar;
        beforeBar, barLength, afterBar];

    aH=area(Y);

    set(aH,'EdgeColor','red');
    aH(1).FaceColor = [0 0 0];
    aH(2).FaceColor = [1 0 0];
    aH(3).FaceColor = [0 0 0];

    if beforeBar>=projectionArea-(target+barLength/2)
        no_contact=false;
    else
        beforeBar=beforeBar+treadmillSpeed*obstacleIncrement;
        pause(obstacleIncrement)
    end

    if isempty(f) || ~ishandle(f) || ~isa(f,'matlab.ui.Figure')
        f = figure;
        set(f, 'MenuBar', 'none', 'ToolBar', 'none', 'Color','black');
    else
        figure(f); %focus window
        drawnow
    end

end
```

Comment: I would also add that re-using `f` to store the area object inside the while loop could lead to unexpected behavior and is not a good idea. Ex.   1st Run`f` is overwritten as the area object.  Close figure then re-run code.  `f` is not empty and is not a figure handle as expected... No new figure with the given properties is created etc.

Comment: @AeroEngy You are right. Previously I tried using `isgraphics()` with no success. I updated the code with a `try catch`. Not a clean solution, but it works. As you suggested, `persistent f` should be removed if not really needed for some unknown reason.

Comment: Perhaps  `ishandle(f) && isa(f,'matlab.ui.Figure')` ... That would make sure it is a valid handle (not dead or deleted) & that its to a figure.    Also,  if it were my code 'f=area(Y)' would become `aH = area(Y)` so you didn't have to worry about what was contained in `f`anyway.

Comment: Yes, now it is better.

Comment: Thank you guys. You have been very helpful. I'm still new at this, so its a bumpy road :)